# php, dynamically creating variables

Tags: php, class, variables, object

(Sorry for my bad English, I use Google Translate)

I'm facing the problem of dynamically creating variables in the class. 
There are classes at the entrance to __construct transferred to variables. 
Further cycles

```
foreach ($collector as $key => $field) {
    $this->$key = $field; 
}
```

Variables are added to the class. 
But this code works in other classes, except one. 
Here is the class

```
foreach ($collector as $key => $field) {
     $this->$key = $field;
            if (isset($this->$key))
              var_dump($this->$key);
        }
     var_dump('<pre>',$collector);
     var_dump($this);
     die();
```

`var_dump('<pre>',$collector)` - dumps the object

```
if (isset($this->$key))
var_dump($this->$key)
```

call magic __get(); since there is no variable

`var_dump($this)` - dumps the object but necessary variables I can not see.

Help me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $_dynamic;

    function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->_dynamic[$name];
    }

    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_dynamic[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```